# InTune : Handle auth through MDM instead of in-app auth

Tags: mdm, intune

I have a Windows app to deploy on Surface tablet using Microsoft MDM/MAM solution: InTune. This app requires user authentication to be used.

- Is there any way to handle app user authentication through the device enrollment system (from InTune) instead of having some classic authentication page/view in-app itself ?
- If yes: does it require source code modification and/or specific InTune setup?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, please note that the MAM policies are only supported on IOS and Android devices at this moment. A windows app in your case are not applicable for MAM.

As far as I know, there's no built-in features in Intune for handling User authentication. Users in Intune use Azure AD for authentication actually. However, you can use Azure AD and ADFS to achieve functions like SSO, Multi-factor authentication, conditional access, etc.